# EC2 Windows User Data: Powershell does not run as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to bootstrap EC2 Windows instances via Powershell commands inside user data. The steps I am trying to execute via user data are:

- Install chocolatey
- Use chocolatey to install Python
- Use chocolatey to install AWS CLI
- Use AWS CLI to download a Powershell script from S3
- Run that Powershell script

The user data is pretty straightforward:

```
<powershell>
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force;
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
choco install python3 -y;
choco install awscli -y

refreshenv

$BootstrapScript = (Join-Path $env:TEMP "NewBootstrap.ps1")
& aws s3api get-object --bucket my-bucket-name --key bootstrap/WindowsBootstrap.ps1 "$BootstrapScript"

iex "$BootstrapScript"
</powershell>
```

The bootstrap script is never downloaded or executed. If I logon to the instance and view the logs, the output suggests something strange is happening:

- At the top of the logs there are errors complaining that `'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. Why should this error before it's even tried to install the aws cli?
- After that `the term 
  'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NewBootstrap.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
  script file`. Again - why is this erroring before we've tried to get that file?
- Then the logs show that choco, python and awscli actually *were* installed correctly.

I don't understand what is happening with the order of execution. If I login to the box and execute the exact same user data script that is contained in `C:\Windows\Temp` it runs completely as expected.

Any help on understanding or debugging this would be most appreciated.

Output from `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log` with some choco output elided for brevity

```
2017/11/06 12:11:49Z: Userdata execution begins
2017/11/06 12:11:49Z: Zero or more than one <persist> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 12:11:49Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
2017/11/06 12:11:54Z: Zero or more than one <runAsLocalSystem> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 12:11:54Z: Zero or more than one <script> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 12:11:54Z: Zero or more than one <powershellArguments> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 12:11:54Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2017/11/06 15:13:42Z: Userdata execution begins
2017/11/06 15:13:42Z: Zero or more than one <persist> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 15:13:42Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
2017/11/06 15:13:54Z: Zero or more than one <runAsLocalSystem> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 15:13:54Z: Zero or more than one <script> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 15:13:54Z: Zero or more than one <powershellArguments> tag was not provided
2017/11/06 15:13:55Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2017/11/06 15:16:11Z: Userdata:  is currently executing. To end it kill the process with id: 2828
2017/11/06 15:17:40Z: Message: The errors from user scripts: & : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\UserScript.ps1:15 char:3
+ & aws s3api get-object --bucket my-bucket-name --key bootstra ...
+   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aws:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NewBootstrap.ps1 : The term 
'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NewBootstrap.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NewBootstrap.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Admini...ewBootstrap.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


2017/11/06 15:17:40Z: Message: The output from user scripts: This is the new bootstrap

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----        11/6/2017   3:14 PM                chocInstall                                                           
Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
Getting Chocolatey from https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.10.8.

... Chocolatey Install output ...

Chocolatey (choco.exe) is now ready.
You can call choco from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing choco.
Run choco /? for a list of functions.
You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles
 first prior to using choco.
Ensuring chocolatey commands are on the path
Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder
Installing awscli
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Installing the following packages:
python3


 .. Python Download / Install output ...

Download of python-3.6.3-amd64.exe (30.16 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing python3...
python3 has been installed.
Installed to 'C:\Python36'
  python3 can be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of python3 was successful.
  Software installed as 'EXE', install location is likely default.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Installing the following packages:
awscli

 .. AWS CLI Download / Install output ...

 The install of awscli was successful.
  Software installed as 'msi', install location is likely default.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait...Finished..

2017/11/06 15:17:40Z: Userdata execution done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that when installed as part of the cloud init process, the Powershell profile fails to import Chocolatey. This means that packages will install fine via `choco install`, but are not made available in the environment, even if you call `refreshenv` (hence my call to `aws` failed even though it installed successfully.)

To fix this problem you can manually force Powershell to import the Chocolatey module by editing your Powershell profile.

```
# Updated profile content to explicitly import Choco
$ChocoProfileValue = @'
$ChocolateyProfile = "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
if (Test-Path($ChocolateyProfile)) {
  Import-Module "$ChocolateyProfile"
}
'@

# Write it to the $profile location
Set-Content -Path "$profile" -Value $ChocoProfileValue -Force

# Source it
. $profile
```

You can read more on this in the [chocolatey troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Troubleshooting#why-does-choco-intab-not-work-for-me)